# PHP + CodeIgniter - Persistir parâmetro da busca em paginação

Tags: php, codeigniter, paginação

Caros amigos

Recorro ao auxilio em PHP+CodeIgniter. Sou novato em CodeIgniter e estou com a seguinte dúvida.

Gostaria de Persistir o parâmetro de Busca em paginação que não estou conseguindo.
Após escolher a categoria do cliente, por exemplo: Pessoa Física ou Jurídica, gostaria que a paginação não perdesse o seu parâmetro.

Observação: quando faço a paginação total, não dá nenhum erro. O erro só ocorre após a escolha do parãmetro.

Abaixo o meu código fonte que estou utilizando.

**=====Model=====**

```
class Clientes_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}


function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);        
    $this->db->order_by('idClientes','asc');
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }        

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}

function getById($id){
    $this->db->where('idClientes',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('clientes')->row();
}

function add($table,$data){
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);         
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;       
}

function edit($table,$data,$fieldID,$ID){
    $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;       
}

function delete($table,$fieldID,$ID){
    $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
    $this->db->delete($table);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;        
}

function count($table) {
    return $this->db->count_all($table);
}

public function getOsByCliente($id){
    $this->db->where('clientes_id',$id);
    $this->db->order_by('idOs','desc');
    $this->db->limit(10);
    return $this->db->get('os')->result();
}
```

}

**=====Controller=====**

```
class Clientes extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
          redirect('siscom/login');
        }

        $this->load->model('clientes_model','',TRUE);
        $this->data['menuClientes'] = 'clientes';
        $this->load->helper(array('codegen_helper'));            
}   

public function index(){
   $this->gerenciar();
}

public function gerenciar(){
    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar clientes.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }


    $busc = '';
    $tipPes = $this->input->get('tipPes');

    // busca todos os lançamentos
    if(! isset($tipPes) || $tipPes == 'todas'){                  
        $busc = ''; 
        } else {
        if($tipPes == 'fisica'){
            $busc = 'tipoPessoa = "fisica"'; 
        } else {
            if($tipPes == 'juridica'){
                $busc = 'tipoPessoa = "juridica"';
            }
        }
    }   


    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('pagination');


    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->clientes_model->count('clientes');
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Próxima';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination alternate"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a style="color: #2D335B"><b>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'Primeira';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Última';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

    $this->data['results'] = $this->clientes_model->get('clientes','idClientes,nomeCliente,documento,tipoPessoa,telefone,celular,email,rua,numero,bairro,cidade,estado,cep',$busc,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/clientes';
    $this->load->view('tema/header',  $this->data);
    $this->load->view('tema/footer');


}

public function autonomo() {
    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aCliente')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar clientes.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

    if ($this->form_validation->run('clientes') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'nomeCliente' => set_value('nomeCliente'),
            'documento' => set_value('documento'),
            'tipoPessoa' =>   $this->input->post('tipoPessoa'),
            'telefone' => set_value('telefone'),
            'celular' => $this->input->post('celular'),
            'email' => set_value('email'),
            'rua' => set_value('rua'),
            'numero' => set_value('numero'),
            'bairro' => set_value('bairro'),
            'cidade' => set_value('cidade'),
            'estado' => set_value('estado'),
            'cep' => set_value('cep'),
            'dataCadastro' => date('Y-m-d')
        );

        if ($this->clientes_model->add('clientes', $data) == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente adicionado com sucesso!');
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/clientes/autonomo/');
        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';
        }
    }
    $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/adicionarFisica';
    $this->load->view('tema/header',  $this->data);
    $this->load->view('tema/footer');

}

public function empresa() {
    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aCliente')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar clientes.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

    if ($this->form_validation->run('clientes') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'nomeCliente' => set_value('nomeCliente'),
            'documento' => set_value('documento'),
            'tipoPessoa' => $this->input->post('tipoPessoa'),
            'telefone' => set_value('telefone'),
            'celular' => $this->input->post('celular'),
            'email' => set_value('email'),
            'rua' => set_value('rua'),
            'numero' => set_value('numero'),
            'bairro' => set_value('bairro'),
            'cidade' => set_value('cidade'),
            'estado' => set_value('estado'),
            'cep' => set_value('cep'),
            'dataCadastro' => date('Y-m-d')
        );

        if ($this->clientes_model->add('clientes', $data) == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente adicionado com sucesso!');
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/clientes/empresa/');
        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';
        }
    }
    $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/adicionarJuridica';
    $this->load->view('tema/header',  $this->data);
    $this->load->view('tema/footer');

}


public function editar() {
    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eCliente')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para editar clientes.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

    if ($this->form_validation->run('clientes') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'nomeCliente' => $this->input->post('nomeCliente'),
            'documento' => $this->input->post('documento'),
            'tipoPessoa' => $this->input->post('tipoPessoa'),
            'telefone' => $this->input->post('telefone'),
            'celular' => $this->input->post('celular'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'rua' => $this->input->post('rua'),
            'numero' => $this->input->post('numero'),
            'bairro' => $this->input->post('bairro'),
            'cidade' => $this->input->post('cidade'),
            'estado' => $this->input->post('estado'),
            'cep' => $this->input->post('cep')
        );

        if ($this->clientes_model->edit('clientes', $data, 'idClientes', $this->input->post('idClientes')) == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente editado com sucesso!');
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/clientes/editar/'.$this->input->post('idClientes'));
        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro</p></div>';
        }
    }


    $this->data['result'] = $this->clientes_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/editarCliente';
    $this->load->view('tema/header',  $this->data);
    $this->load->view('tema/footer');

}

public function visualizar(){

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar clientes.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $this->data['result'] = $this->clientes_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['results'] = $this->clientes_model->getOsByCliente($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/visualizar';
    $this->load->view('tema/header',  $this->data);
    $this->load->view('tema/footer');


}

public function excluir(){

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dCliente')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para excluir clientes.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }


        $id =  $this->input->post('id');
        if ($id == null){

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Erro ao tentar excluir cliente.');            
            redirect(base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/');
        }

        //$id = 2;
        // excluindo OSs vinculadas ao cliente
        $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
        $os = $this->db->get('os')->result();

        if($os != null){

            foreach ($os as $o) {
                $this->db->where('os_id', $o->idOs);
                $this->db->delete('servicos_os');

                $this->db->where('os_id', $o->idOs);
                $this->db->delete('produtos_os');


                $this->db->where('idOs', $o->idOs);
                $this->db->delete('os');
            }
        }

        // excluindo Vendas vinculadas ao cliente
        $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
        $vendas = $this->db->get('vendas')->result();

        if($vendas != null){

            foreach ($vendas as $v) {
                $this->db->where('vendas_id', $v->idVendas);
                $this->db->delete('itens_de_vendas');


                $this->db->where('idVendas', $v->idVendas);
                $this->db->delete('vendas');
            }
        }

        //excluindo receitas vinculadas ao cliente
        $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('lancamentos');



        $this->clientes_model->delete('clientes','idClientes',$id); 

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente excluido com sucesso!');            
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/');
}
```

}

**=====View=====**

```
<?php if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aCliente')){ ?>
<div class="span5" style="margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/clientes/empresa" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Pessoa Jurídica</a>    
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/clientes/autonomo" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Pessoa Física</a>
```

```
<?php $tipPes = $this->input->get('tipPes'); ?>
<div class="span7" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -17px;">
<form action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" method="get" >
    <div class="span4" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                <label><strong>Situação</strong> <i class="icon-info-sign tip-top" title="Selecione o Tipo de Pessoa."></i></label>
                <select id="tipPes" name="tipPes" class="span12" style="margin-top: -4px;">
                    <option selected disabled class="text-hide">Selecione uma opção...</option>                     
                    <option value="todas">Todas</option>
                    <option value="fisica" <?php if($tipPes == 'fisica'){ echo 'selected';} ?>>Fisica</option>
                    <option value="juridica" <?php if($tipPes == 'juridica'){ echo 'selected';} ?>>Jurídica</option>
                </select>
    </div>    

    <div class="span4" style="margin-top: 0px;">
       &nbsp <button type="submit" class="span12 btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-search"></i> Pesquisar</button>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
```

```
 <div class="widget-box">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <h5>Clientes</h5>

    </div>

    <div class="widget-content nopadding">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>CPF/CNPJ</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Pessoa</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">Nenhum Cliente Cadastrado</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="widget-box">
 <div class="widget-title">
    <span class="icon">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
     </span>
    <h5>Clientes</h5>

 </div>
```

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF/CNPJ</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Pessoa</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($results as $r) {

        //Comando para mudar a cor do texto - Pessoa Física e Jurídica
        if($r->tipoPessoa == 'juridica'){ $text = 'success'; } else { $text = 'info'; }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center">'.$r->idClientes.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$r->nomeCliente.'</td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center">'.$r->documento.'</td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center">'.$r->telefone.'</td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">
                  <strong class="text text-'.$text.'">'.ucfirst($r->tipoPessoa).'</strong></td>';  
        echo '<td style="text-align: center">';
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
            echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/clientes/visualizar/'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn tip-top" title="Ver mais detalhes"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>'; 
        }
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eCliente')){
            echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/clientes/editar/'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-info tip-top" title="Editar Cliente"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a>'; 
        }
        if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dCliente')){
            echo '<a href="#modal-excluir" role="button" data-toggle="modal" cliente="'.$r->idClientes.'" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-danger tip-top" title="Excluir Cliente"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></a>'; 
        }


        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }?>
    <tr>

    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();}?>




<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal-excluir" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/clientes/excluir" method="post" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h5 id="myModalLabel">Excluir Cliente</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="idCliente" name="id" value="" />
    <h5 style="text-align: center">Deseja realmente excluir este cliente e os dados associados a ele (OS, Vendas, Receitas)?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


   $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var cliente = $(this).attr('cliente');
        $('#idCliente').val(cliente);

    });

});

</script>
```

Por favor, poderia me auxiliar nesta dúvida.

Grato,

Renato

Answer (score 0):

Na configuração da sua paginação, tenta colocar isso:

```
$config["base_url"] = site_url('clientes/gerenciar/page');
$config['first_url'] = site_url('clientes/gerenciar/page/1').(!empty($this->input->get()) ? '?'.http_build_query($this->input->get()) : ''); 
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config["reuse_query_string"] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Caro amigo. Agradeço sua atenção, mas infelizmente não deu certo, continua perdendo o foco da busca.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">

  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-md">
  <?php
  $anterior=$pagina-1;
  $classAnterior=$pagina==1 ? "disabled" : "";
?>
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $classAnterior; ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <?php
    $inicio = $pagina > $itens_por_pagina ? $pagina - $itens_por_pagina + 1 : 1;

    //$final= $pagina > $itens ? $pagina : $itens > $numero_paginas ? $numero_paginas : $itens;

    if($pagina > $itens_por_pagina){
      $final=$pagina;
    }else{

      if($itens_por_pagina > $numero_paginas){
        $final=$numero_paginas;
      }else{
        $final=$itens_por_pagina;
      }
    }

    for( $i=$inicio; $i<=$final; $i++) { ?>

        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>

   <?php } ?>


   <?php
  $proximo=$pagina+1;
  $classProximo=$pagina == $numero_paginas ? "disabled" : "";
?>
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $classProximo; ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $proximo; ?>" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

[link para o google drive com projeto completo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kv-cACBcLmHF43qp4_U0v-6AnXHEYxCV)

Comment: Seja mais claro ao responder. Só apresentar o código pode não ajudar, pois além do usuário outras pessoas que possuem problema similar também procurarão essa pergunta no futuro. Também não deixe o código da reposta em link ainda mais para driver virtual.